# std::transform with std::istream_iterator

Tags: c++, istream-iterator

Say I have a string containing numbers separated by empty spaces. I want to insert the numbers into a vector of integers, where every number is decreased by one. So for example:

```
"1 2 3 4" -> {0, 1, 2, 3}
```

Now the plan was to use `std::transform` in combination with a `std::istream_iterator<int>`, which looks like the following:

```
std::istringstream source{"1 2 3 4"};
std::vector<int> target;

std::transform(std::istream_iterator<int>(source),
               std::istream_iterator<int>(),
               std::begin(target),
               [](int a) {
                 return a-1;
               }
);
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work because `std::transform` expects `target` to already be of the right size. So I have to do

```
std::vector<int> target(4);
```

Now I have two questions. How can I dynamically find the right size for `target` beforehand? Is there a more elegant way to achieve the actual goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While researching for this question, I found a simple solution. Simply use `std::back_inserter` as output iterator instead of `std::begin(target)`.

```
std::transform(std::istream_iterator<int>(source),
               std::istream_iterator<int>(),
               std::back_inserter(target),
               [](int a) {
                 return a-1;
               }
);
```

Another [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/527179/6608142) uses `std::for_each`:

```
std::for_each(std::istream_iterator<int>(source),
              std::istream_iterator<int>(),
              [&target](int a) {
                target.push_back(a-1);
              }
);
```